# Conditional formatting FlexTable

Tags: r, reporters

I am looking for a way to conditionally format a flextable with ReporteRs using percentage figures. Below is a small example.

```
packs <- list("ReporteRs","scales")
lapply(packs,require,character.only = TRUE)

dat <- cbind.data.frame(rep("ABCD",2),c(0.07,0.11),c(0.03,0.01))
colnames(dat) <- c("A","B","C")
dat[,2] <- percent(dat[,2])

pp = pptx()
pp = addSlide(pp, "Title and Content")
datft = FlexTable(data = dat)
cname <- c("B","C") 

for (i in cname) {
   if (i=="B") {
   datft[dat[, i] <= 10, i] = cellProperties( background.color = "green" )
   datft[dat[, i] > 10, i] = cellProperties( background.color = "red" )
   } else if (i=="C") {
   datft[dat[, i] <= 0.02, i] = cellProperties( background.color = "green" )
   datft[dat[, i] > 0.02, i] = cellProperties( background.color = "red" )   
   }
}
pp = addFlexTable(pp, datft)
writeDoc(pp, paste(getwd(),"/example.pptx",sep=""))
```

This works fine for column C but obviously not column B, as it's not numeric. I couldn't figure out a way to apply a function that formats the values to percentage figures after the backgroundcolor is changed.

Comment: It looks as I would expect it to look. The B column is character so asking for less than or greater than tests will be using lexical ordering where "10" is less than "2". If you want to test he numeric portion than you need as.numeric around a sub() removal of the %-sign.

Comment: Thanks for this question. I'm a first time user of `pkg:ReportRs`. This looks like a promising package. I've used a workflow of R -> Excel -> PPT in the past with both a 80:20 split of successes and annoying failures.

Comment: Great and yet simple workaround! Still have lots to learn... ReporteRs is indeed a great package, quit usefull for reoccuring reportings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (with the explanation in the comment but after testing):

```
for (i in cname) {
   if (i=="B") {
   datft[as.numeric( sub("%", "", dat[, i])) <= 10, i] = cellProperties( background.color = "green" )
   datft[ as.numeric( sub("%", "", dat[, i])) > 10, i] = cellProperties( background.color = "red" )
   } else if (i=="C") {
   datft[dat[, i] <= 0.02, i] = cellProperties( background.color = "green" )
   datft[dat[, i] > 0.02, i] = cellProperties( background.color = "red" )   
   }
}
```